# jquery unobtrusive validation dependencies resolving

Tags: jquery, validation, unobtrusive

I have a problem with using unobtrusive jquery -Uncought type error cannot set property unobtrusive of 'undefined' on page load  and the resource is not loaded
I am using :
 * jQuery Validation Plugin 1.8.1
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.4.4
Jquery.validate.Unobtrusive

Answer (score 0):

Make sure about javascript order

```
1. jquery.js

2. jquery.validate

3. jquery.validate.unobtrusive or other jquery.validate.additional script
```

Comment: The problem that appeared is that jquery.validate.unobtrusive
doesnt work in mvc2